# Oracle tutorial doesn't work out in the versions I've tried - a prep issue or does my Oracle lack magic powers?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

here's an official Oracle tutorial about filling in sparse data to make it more dense:

[image]

I was reading it, arrived at the highlighted table and thought to myself.. "cool. Oracle has a magic table called `times` that generates an arbitrary number of dates when selected from."

Sadly, this seems not to be true. I scoured the [rest of the tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/outerjoin/outerjoin_otn.htm) for any indication where this mystery "times" table might have come from but didn't notice anything that created it..

I also looked in the full scripts (download link at the tutorial top) that the tutorial recommended (ci.sql, nn.sql), expecting to find that the SQLs within the tutorial were not the only things in the file, and there would be something else like `WITH times as (SELECT blahmath FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL ...)` that would generate the relevant table, but didn't find anything there either

So, is there a special version of Oracle that has pseudo/arbitrary-row-generating tables (cool feature if it did, nudge nudge Oracle) or is the explanation more mundane?

Comment: Sounds like the tutorial is missing the create table statement for the `times` table. There is no version of the Oracle database that has arbitrary row generating tables by default - you have to create and maintain them yourself, as you would with any other table or view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `times` table is from [the Oracle sample schema "SH"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14198/installation.htm#sthref45) (for Sales History). If it already exists, you'll probably want to create a synonym or refer to it as `sh.times`. If the SH schema doesn't exist, I think for 10g you should be able to install it by running $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/sales_history/sh_main.sql

In my experience, Oracle tutorials will often just assume that everyone already has the sample schemas installed.

If you don't want to install the full sample schema, it looks like somebody put [the scripts on github](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/tree/master/sales_history), so you could try just creating the times table and using sqlldr to load the time_v3 dataset.